# Textarea Height increase

Tags: jquery, textbox, textarea

How to increase the height of the text area as and when we type to a max of 50px from 18px. then if someone types more the scrollbar should take over. is this possible ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use either of these plugins:

- [TextAreaExpander (Demo)](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/textarea-expander/index.html)
- [autoResize Plugin](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-plugin-autoresize/)

Answer (score 0):

That's [JQuery Elastic](http://www.unwrongest.com/projects/elastic/). It might be your requirement. :)