# How to count numbers of line in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, jquery-events, keyup

I want to make a dynamic textarea, it should increase in rows as the content increase.

I am using this code:

```
$("#text_textarea").keyup(function(e) {
    //splitting textarea value wrt '\n' to count the number of lines
    if ($(this).val().lastIndexOf('\n')!=-1)
    var x = $(this).val().split('\n');
    $(this).attr( "rows" , x.length+1 );
});
```

But it fails when user continues to write without giving any new line `\n` (pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

Comment: Do you mean the word-wrapping that takes place when it doesn't fit on one line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Autosizing Textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477/autosizing-textarea) -- the code in the accepted answer shows how to address this problem.

Comment: The situation is unfortunately horrible because of the strange rules that the standard mandates for handling of word wrapping. Even worse than the event mouse position if you know what I mean.

Comment: @pimvdb yes yes you are right. That word warping which takes place result to an increase of line. that cannot be detected by this code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var keyUpTimeout = false; // Required variables for performance
var keyupTimer = 0;

$("#text_textarea").keyup(function(e) {
    var cooldownTimeout = 500;
    //Set the cooldown time-out. The height check will be executed when the user
    // hasn't initiated another keyup event within this time
    
    var ths = this;
    function heightCheck(){
        keyupTimer = false;
        // Reset height, so that the textarea can shrink when necessary
        ths.style.height = "";

        // Set the height of the textarea
        var newheight = this.scrollHeight + 2;
        ths.style.height = newheight + "px";
    }
    if(keyupTimeout){ //Has a cooldown been requested?
        clearTimeout(keyupTimer); //This+next line: Refresh cooldown timeout.
        keyUpTimer = setTimeout(heightCheck, cooldownTimeout);
        return; //Return, to avoid unnecessary calculations
    }
    
    // Set a cooldown
    keyupTimer = setTimeout(heightCheck, cooldownTimeout);
    keyupTimeout = true; //Request a cooldown
});
```

This piece of script will change the height of the textarea to fit the text inside.

#### Update

I have added an additional feature: To improve performance (changing the CSS height requires a significant amount of computer power), I have added a cooldown effect: The height check will only be executed when the user hasn't initiated a `keyup` event for 500 milliseconds (adjust this value to meet your wishes).

Comment: This is quit good. But in this code textarea height once increases does not decreases even the content is deleted or content height is decreased

Comment: Add `this.style.height="";` before `var x = ...`.

Comment: Yes its working.. But I don't know why the performance is reduced somehow (bit slow responce) while writing. I think because of calling the function on every keyup. Can it be corrected?

Answer (score 2):

read this,

[Textarea Height increase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176783/textarea-height-increase)

---

[TextAreaExpander (Demo)](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/textarea-expander/index.html)

[autoResize Plugin](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-plugin-autoresize/)

[JQuery Elastic](http://www.unwrongest.com/projects/elastic/)

Comment: You could have elaboratedt he purpose of these references, rather than replying "read this, <bunch of links>"

Comment: thanks for the comment,yes the same thing I want.But I don't want to use any plugin. Can you elaborate what the logic has been used in those plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the attribute `wrap='hard'` on your textarea.

Comment: It seems that this attribute is proprietary.. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I write this code. what about it..

```
$("#text_textarea").keyup(function(e) {
    var textarea_height = Number($(this).css('height').replace("px", ""))+4;
    var scroll_height = this.scrollHeight;

    if(textarea_height < scroll_height ){   
        $(this).css('height' ,"");
        var x = Number(scroll_height) + 3;
            if(x != $(this).height()) 
        $(this).css("height", x+"px");
     }
});
```