# Emptying keyboard buffer in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have an element that responses on

```
$('#div').keydown(function(event) { ....
```

and if user presses a key like a crazy rabbit on heat thousand times within a really short period, browser responses on most of those calls.

Can I somehow prevent that by flushing keyboard buffer?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to prevent?  Fast typing?  You can simply choose to ignore keystrokes that come within N ms of the previous key.

Comment: Just make sure you do not block people who actually type fast. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may checkout the [following blog post](http://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls/) which illustrates how you could throttle down function calls and calm down the crazy rabbits.

```
function debounce(fn, delay) {
  var timer = null;
  return function () {
    var context = this, args = arguments;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
      fn.apply(context, args);
    }, delay);
  };
}

$('input.username').keypress(debounce(function (event) {
  // do the Ajax request
}, 250));
```

Comment: @Agzam, it's just that I have already gone through all of this in my experience.

Comment: Still how do you remember? I don't even remember what I ate on breakfast. :) Thanks buddy...

Comment: @Agzam, me neither, I don't remember anything. All I know is that I am drinking my beer at the moment and if I needed to find something I just google it.

Answer (score 3):

This is an easy method to deal with an excessive number of keydown calls.

```
var timeout = false; //I'd recommend defining this variable within a local scope

$('#div').keydown(function(event) {
    if(timeout) return;
    timeout = true;
    setTimeout(function(){timeout=false}, 100);
    //Change 100 to something more appropriate

    //Rest of function
}
```

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do in this code, but the variable `timeout` NEVER gets a falsey value in it once the first key is pressed.

Comment: I think the `timeout = true` statement before setting the timeout is redundant; you overwrite it immediately.

Comment: @pimvdb Did you read the question? This addition will only show a sign of life when the user has an incredibly fast typing ability.

Comment: @Rob W: Yes, perhaps I misunderstand, but in the meantime `timeout` will have the timeout's ID, not the `true` value. Could you tell me the reason of storing the timeout's ID into the `timeout` variable?

Comment: My bad, my mind was occupied by a delaying method (as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460815/how-to-count-numbers-of-line-in-a-textarea/7460821#7460821)).